# how to get hashmap key and value from a string?

Tags: java, listview, javafx, hashmap

```
HashMap<LocalDate, String>
```

i have a ListView that contain strings (for example : "2014-05-10 example") and i want to delete the selected hashmap with

```
hashmap.remove(LocalDate key, String value)
```

but i'm not sure how to get the key and value from a string

[Context](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vAri3.png)

my object is from a class called "Inv" :

```
public class Inv {
    private String name;
    private String category;
    private LocalDate date;
    private Double price;
    private String info;
    private HashMap<LocalDate, String> mapMain;
```

context: the object from the "Inv" class is something that you bought for example a car and the hashmap contain all the maintenances that has been done to the car.

can you please help ?

Comment: `hashmap.remove(LocalDate.parse(text.split(" ")[0]))`

Comment: Where is the string coming from? Don't you have the date on its own, as a `LocalDate`, at some point?

Comment: How long is a piece of string?

Comment: “A piece of string is twice as long as half its length” :-)

Answer (score 0):

There is no general solution to "how do I get a key and value from a string".

It depends on whether you can:

- unambiguously parse the string into a key and value information, and
- recreate a key object from it.

Note that you need to be able to construct an object that will be `equal` to the original key.  If you can't, then the problem cannot be solved.

In your case, if we can assume that the date string will always be in that format, then @Andreas's solution should work:

```
    hashmap.remove(LocalDate.parse(text.split(" ")[0]))
```

But here's a counter-example:

```
    HashMap<String, String>
```

and entries like this:

```
    "key example string"
    "key 2 another example"
```

Now we can't be sure where the key ends and the value starts.  (Is the "2" part of the key or the value?   What about "example"?)

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation: Don't use a `ListView` containing key-value pairs as items instead of `String` and use custom `ListCell`s to display them properly.

**Example:**

```
Map<LocalDate, String> data = ...
ListView<Map.Entry<LocalDate, String>> listView = new ListView<>();
listView.getItems().addAll(data.entrySet());
listView.setCellFactory(l -> new ListCell<Map.Entry<LocalDate, String>>() {

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(Map.Entry<LocalDate, String> item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        setText((empty || item == null) ? "" : item.getKey() + " " + item.getValue());
    }

});
```

in this case you can remove the selected entry like this:

```
int index = listView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();
if (index >= 0) { // check, if selection exists
    Map.Entry<LocalDate, String> entry = listView.getItems().remove(index);
    // data.remove(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    data.remove(entry.getKey());
}
```